# Wagtail 5.0 -> 5.1 Update fails: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT)

Tags: mariadb, wagtail

I updated my Wagtail 5.0.3 installation to 5.1.3

After runing the migrations for wagtailcore I get this error:

```
    python3 manage.py migrate wagtailcore


      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
        return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 73, in execute
        return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 179, in execute
        res = self._query(mogrified_query)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 330, in _query
        db.query(q)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 261, in query
        _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
    MySQLdb.OperationalError: (1267, "Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='")
```

Why is Wagtail 5.1.3 not working with my MariaDB DB?

I use Python 3.11 and Django 3.2

What changes I have to do to my tables to make it workable with Wagtail?

Comment: which sql command are you running

Comment: I don't know what Django is doing in the background. I just run: python3 manage.py migrate wagtailcore

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to change all tables to the same collation:

I used this command to change the collations:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

I don't understand why I had different collations. I use Django for many years and it seams like that it changed the default collation at some point.

Comment: they changed the database that is why the migration script tries to change it